# Firing the JQuery Dialog using an ASP.NET Button?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a Page which has a Control on it with 2 textboxes (username and password) and an asp:Button.  If the user's membership is going to expire within 30 days and the button is clicked, I want the JQuery dialog to popup.  Inside the JQuery dialog, I have some text and an asp:LinkButton.  The link button has an event attached to it, but it is not being fired when I click it in the dialog box.  Here is the script tags for the JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui.resizable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui.dialog.js"></script>
```

Here is the script the dialog: For testing, I am closing the dialog on Renew Membership click, but I actually want it to fire a method I create in asp.net to direct the user to a another page and pass a session variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
         // autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: { "Renew Membership": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:Content ID="mainContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content">
<div id="dialog" title="Membership Renewal">
    <p>Uh Oh! Your membership is going to expire.</p><br />
    <p>Hurry up and renew today!</p><br />
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Click Here to Renew" 
        onclick="Unnamed2_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

Here is the click event for the LinkButton:

```
protected void Unnamed2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserProfiles userProfile = (UserProfiles)Session["userProfile"];
    Response.Redirect("~/Renew.aspx");
}
```

What should happen is that when the user clicks the sign-in button, it should popup up the dialog only if the days they have left to expire is <= 30 and if they do, they have the option of clicking the link in the dialog and going to a renew page where I want to pass it a Session variable with a Profile, but that is not being called, so I guess, I would like to know is how can I add the event handler of the button to the dialog and is there a way to set it so that it only comes up once, for example adding a cookie to the users browser and only showing it if they don't have a cookie set.

Comment: I updated my post to include the 30 expiration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is more of an ASP.NET issue and not a jQuery dialog issue.

I wouldn't use the onClick and PostBackUrl within the same LinkButton.  So, take off the PostBackUrl attribute and instead use

```
protected void Unnamed2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    UserProfiles userProfile = (UserProfiles)Session["userProfile"];
    Response.Redirect("~/Renew.aspx");
}
```

If you only need to show the control when the user is > 30 days.  I would create a user control.

**jquery.renewDialog.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true
    });
});
```

**RenewalUserControl.ascx**

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="ScriptManager1">
  <Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="jquery.renewDialog.js" />
  </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div id="dialog" title="Membership Renewal">
    <p>Uh Oh! Your membership is going to expire.</p><br />
    <p>Hurry up and renew today!</p><br />
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Click Here to Renew" 
        onclick="Unnamed2_Click" />
</div>
```

**Login.aspx**

```
<uc1:RenewalUserControl runat="server" ID="RenewalUserControl1" Visible="false" />
```

**Login.aspx.cs**

```
if (user.IsExpired)
{
  RenewalUserControl1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I removed the PostBackUrl and now it is redirected to the page correctly.  Now, I set the autoOpen to false in the dialog and I want an asp:button which is located in a control to fire the dialog only if the users expiration is less than or equal to 30 days.

Comment: Correct me If I am wrong?  You are encapsulating the JQuery dialog in a user control and setting it to visible when the user expiration is <= 30 days.  Does the dialog popup only when the Renew Control is shown and what if you don't want it to popup everytime.

Comment: Yea the beauty here is that if the user control isn't visible the jquery and the dialog shell aren't written out to the html at all.